# sort a list of dicts by x then by y

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort this info(name, points, and time):

```
list = [
    {'name':'JOHN', 'points' : 30, 'time' : '0:02:2'},
    {'name':'KARL','points':50,'time': '0:03:00'}
]
```

so, what I want is the list sorted first by points made, then by time played (in my example, matt go first because of his less time. any help?

I'm trying with this:

```
import operator
list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('points', 'time'))
```

but got a `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`.

Comment: What version of python?  Your example works on 2.7.  Also, as a reminder "list" is a typename.

Comment: @koblas I might be to blame. This example works for me too now, but I edited the question to format the source code, and inadvertently corrected a syntax error in the definition of ``list``. Ignoring the fact that the variable name ``list`` clobbers a builtin, once the syntax error of an incorrectly terminated string literal was fixed, things work...

Comment: Can't be a python version issue, I use python 2.6.6. And sorry, my fault, in fact list is not my variable name, I don't know why I use it here. I think there is something wrong with the "time played" that I have converted to string...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your example works for me. I would advise you not to use `list` as a variable name, since it is a builtin type.

You could try doing something like this also:

```
list.sort(key=lambda item: (item['points'], item['time']))
```

Answer (score 9):

**edit:**

### example list:

```
>>> a = [
...     {'name':'JOHN', 'points' : 30, 'time' : '0:02:20'},
...     {'name':'LEO', 'points' : 30, 'time': '0:04:20'},
...     {'name':'KARL','points':50,'time': '0:03:00'},
...     {'name':'MARK','points':50,'time': '0:02:00'},
... ]
```

### descending 'points':

using sort() for inplace sorting:

```
>>> a.sort(key=lambda x: (-x['points'],x['time']))
>>> pprint.pprint(a)
[{'name': 'MARK', 'points': 50, 'time': '0:02:00'},
 {'name': 'KARL', 'points': 50, 'time': '0:03:00'},
 {'name': 'JOHN', 'points': 30, 'time': '0:02:20'},
 {'name': 'LEO', 'points': 30, 'time': '0:04:20'}]
>>>
```

using sorted to return a sorted list:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(sorted(a, key=lambda x: (-x['points'],x['time'])))
[{'name': 'MARK', 'points': 50, 'time': '0:02:00'},
 {'name': 'KARL', 'points': 50, 'time': '0:03:00'},
 {'name': 'JOHN', 'points': 30, 'time': '0:02:20'},
 {'name': 'LEO', 'points': 30, 'time': '0:04:20'}]
>>>
```

### **ascending 'points':**

```
>>> a.sort(key=lambda x: (x['points'],x['time']))
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(a)
[{'name': 'JOHN', 'points': 30, 'time': '0:02:20'},
 {'name': 'LEO', 'points': 30, 'time': '0:04:20'},
 {'name': 'MARK', 'points': 50, 'time': '0:02:00'},
 {'name': 'KARL', 'points': 50, 'time': '0:03:00'}]
>>>
```

Comment: In your example, MARK should be the first, because he has more points, KARL 2nd (same points but more time), and so on..

Comment: fixed, you wanted to sort the reverse of points which can be accomplished by multiplying by negative 1 or negation.

Answer (score 3):

itemgetter will throw this error up to Python2.4

If you are stuck on 2.4, you will need to use the lambda

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: (x['points'], x['time']))
```

It would be preferable to upgrade to a newer Python if possible