# How to sort a list of tuple by second then by first?

Tags: python

I am looking to sort a list of tuple starting with the second item then by the first item. This is not a duplicate from [Sort tuple by first then second then third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995548/sort-tuple-by-first-then-second-then-third), because this post is about first then second and not second then first.

Coming from a C# background, I would have lot to find something like [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8)+[ThenBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netframework-4.8).

I could write my own and ship it. Python is battery included, I am sure there is a better way to achieve this.

[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with unit tests:

```python
def sort_tuples_by_second(inputs):
    return sorted(inputs, key=lambda item: item[1])

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    # both passed
    def test_sort_tuples_by_second(self):
        tuples = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 0), (0, 9)]
        actuals = sort_tuples_by_second(tuples)
        self.assertEqual(actuals, [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 9)])
        letters = [("a", "a"), ("b", "c"), ("c", "b"), ("a", "z")]
        actuals = sort_tuples_by_second(letters)
        self.assertEqual(actuals, [("a", "a"), ("c", "b"), ("b", "c"), ("a", "z")])

    # both failed
    def test_sort_tuples_by_second_then_by_first(self):
        tuples = [(1, 1), (4, 1), (3, 1), (1, 9), (0, 9)]
        actuals = sort_tuples_by_second(tuples)
       	self.assertEqual(actuals, [(1, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (0, 9), (1, 9)])
        letters = [("b", "a"), ("a", "a")]
        actuals = sort_tuples_by_second(letters)
        self.assertEqual(actuals, [("a", "a"), ("b", "a")])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZNBT4MwFMfP8ime7EIN28B5cEs4Gb15cp6WpSlQXCMUbMthfnlsKTBIFp0xsYe@x@t7/f15L62O6lDyVTO7XtZSLGPGl5UNOTOY38whKVPG3zbwun2a35uI47CiKoWCmjOlqFRNSjOQOoJVXeVU4viIJU1KnnqMV7WSaOOAXoKqWvA2k/ZHPrzTY5STIk4J6PINeHrfhXuEHCfJiZSw1YgXJbSIZ6qFpdLrwQtz9EAk1YCWMIO4VAeodBlN24iRZlLxeX2S5lmnzix7DhHsvNCHEPlg7G1nA2MDH9ZoP1SQRNUkNyXnATaAhnwDXBh5Qj1@6Eqvu8C3yKBDTdAWebojp/rvhZXpEtcHvZk8NzZ@Yv3E@LH125xP9xeyO8RluicaxtyxnkEDmowqIyy/aFRYHSg3nxkTUl0wuLvOrk7dXP99gFc/DHCC7CUEHTr8bpDxqIl9Q/9jYD1X62pYBhhzUlCMIYrAxbggjGPs2k4P785EPdR8AQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a builtin way and there are two! You could have found them by looking at how python dev sort others data structures. As example, some hints are present on [sort a list of dicts by x then by y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944630/sort-a-list-of-dicts-by-x-then-by-y#5944671). In there case, they sort by key:

```
list.sort(key=lambda item: (item['points'], item['time']))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZPPT4MwFMfP8lc82QUM25jz4JZwMnrzpJ6WpSlQtkZosS2H@c9jSwsbyaIzJnLgvb4f/X54L9QHteds2U6u540U85SyeW1D3gSmN1PIeE7Zbg1vr0/TexPxPFrVXChoGFWKSOUVglfAayKw4gJclipS7YguEG1OCpA6hlRTl0Si9IAkyTjLA8rqRslw7YF@BFGNYF0l6VMRvJNDUuIqzXF35RoCYzaLbdSdN/E2DD0vK7GU8KppXpTQvM9Ef0Mug55xZlIPWBKt1YlNIOVqD7VuI3kXMZSmFJ1HlaQsHKh5bB4S2ASLCBZhBMbeOhsbG0ewCrdDB85Ug0vTcl7ABsKh3gjODJ5Qjx@6M3AXRFYydlIjaSt5vKPsFmAxfexHoF@mzk@Nn1k/M35q/a7m0/8FtpO4jHvEcKp7yjMwhKNVFZiWF60KqT1h5lhQIdUFi7tzdnmc5urvC7z6YYEjyR4hdtKL7xaZngyxH@h/LKzX1VwtLQAhhiuCECQJ@AhVmDKEfDvp4b8z0SBsvwA)

or in you case with a tuple:

```
sorted(inputs, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0]))
```

Python's [HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) offers an alternative:

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted(inputs, key=itemgetter(1, 0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZPPT4MwFMfP8lc82YUatjHnwS3hZPTmST0Z0xQoWyO02JbD/OexpWUbyaIzJnLgPd6v7yfvhWant4Ivu8nlvFVynjE@b1womMD0agq5KBjfrOHl@WF6ayNBwOpGSA0tZ1pTpYNSihpEQyXRQoLPMk3rDTUFsitoCcrEsG6biiqc7bCiueBFxHjTaoXWAZhHUt1K3lfSIRXDO92lh1nRIk4QCoK8IkrBs1F/0tLwPVLDXKhoYJrZ1B1R1Mzuh08gE3oLjWmjRR@xVLYUn0ZTtCo9mH1cHlJ4NQiwQDFYe@1tYm0Swwq97TtIrltS2ZbTAi6A9vVWcGbxpL7/MJ2RHxA7ycRLjaSd5GFG1S/JYYYkjMG8bF2YWT93fm79zPl9zWf4C2wvcR73iOFY95hnz4BGpyoJq846FdZbyu1nyaTSZxzuxtvlYZurvx/w4ocDjiQHhMRLL747ZHa0xGGh/3GwQddwdawEjDmpKcaQphBiXBPGMQ7dpvf/nY1GqPsC)

Comment: you asked and you answered why ??

Comment: @Amy because I could not find the answer online. While writing the question, I resolved my problem. Now, I post it to help others. Read [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) by one of Stack Overflow's founder.

Comment: great job keep it continue and thanks for answer

Comment: Actually, there are various questions that already cover the same topic, with this probably being the more close to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-fields

Comment: @musicamante I didnt find it before.I am glad this exist. I found it strange that my question wasnt already posted. Thank you for finding it!